# Number Grouping in a cell that is different from current locale

Tags: excel

I am working in Excel in en-IN locale. In this, number grouping goes 3 digits for the first group, then groups of 2 digits. That is, the number 10 million is grouped like this:

`1,00,00,000`

The Accounting format for this locale in Excel is like this:

`_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0 ;_-[$$-en-US]* "-"_ ;_-@_`

So, INR 10 million formatted gives me (no decimal places):

[image]

Now, I want to convert this amount to USD using the prevalent exchange rate. Assuming it is ₹80 for $1, I get $125,000. This number is calculated in a different cell in the same spreadsheet.

The problem is, I cannot get Excel to format the cell showing the USD amount with 3-digits grouping. Whatever I try, the cell is always populated as:

[image]

I tried this custom format also (I got this by editing the Accounting format after reading the Microsoft documentation):

`_-$* #,###0_ ;_-$* -#,###0 ;_-[$$-en-US]* "-"_ ;_-@_`

But no luck. I need the USD amount to be formatted as $125,000. Please help.

Note that the above is just an example; I have small numbers (below 10,000), very large numbers (running into billions) both with positive and negative signs.

Edit 1: Adding a screenshot to show why @Harun24hr's solution is not working.

[image]

Edit 2: Managed to do this with Conditional Formatting. Like this (note that each of the format strings have a space at the end):

```
is 0:

=OR(ISBLANK(A1), A1 = 0)
_-$* "-"_ 

between -999 and +999:

=AND(ABS(A1) > 0, ABS(A1) < 1000)
_-$* ###_ ;_-$* -###_ 

between -999999 and +999999:

=AND(ABS(A1) >= 1000, ABS(A1) < 1000000)
_-$* ###","###_ ;_-$* -###","###_ 

between -999999999 and +999999999:

=AND(ABS(A1) >= 1000000, ABS(A1) < 1000000000)
_-$* ###","###","###_ ;_-$* -###","###","###_ 

between -999999999999 and +999999999999:

=AND(ABS(A1) >= 1000000000, ABS(A1) < 1000000000000)
_-$* ###","###","###","###_ ;_-$* -###","###","###","###_
```

Comment: It is due to your OS regional settings. "Digit grouping" to be precise and I'm not quite sure, but I think it is not possible to use 2 different groupings at the same time. You could give a try changing these settings and then try to use formatting: https://superuser.com/questions/1776441/how-to-change-excel-number-delimiter-formatting-defaults

Comment: Try: `[>=1000000]$_ ###","###","###;[>=1000]$_ ###","###;$_ 0` or `INR` --> `[>=1000000]₹_ ###","###","###;[>=1000]₹_ ###","###;₹_ 0`

Comment: What a coincidence, I have the exact same issue and upon search discovered this thread. I struggled to get a format to override the regional setting, but @MayukhBhattacharya answer worked perfectly! Mayukh you may want to write it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: It didn't, actually. I have numbers going up to a trillion and the conditionals in the format string didn't scale that much. I have now done what I originally needed by adapting @MayukhBhattacharya 's solution into Conditional Formatting.

Comment: "Managed to do this with Conditional Formatting. Like this (note that each of the format strings have a space at the end):" - did it solve your question? if so, you could post an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

Simple cell format `#,##0` should give you desired result.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't; that's the reason I posted the question. Added a screenshot on  how it looks with your suggestion.

Comment: Interesting. May be regional setting related issue.

Comment: Yes indeed, as the first line of my post says - my Windows & Office installation are with en-IN locale.